# WPF ListView GridView cells styling and binding

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to bind a `DataTable` to a ListView. Since the number of columns is unknown, the binding is done programmatically. There are basically two ways of binding: `DisplayMemberBinding` and templates. How can I either style `DisplayMemberBinding` or bind a template to a cell?

Here is my code:

```
    private void FillListView(DataTable table)
    {
        GridView grid = (GridView)lvMain.View;

        DataTemplate template = (DataTemplate)FindResource("cellTemplate");

        foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
        {
            var gridColumn = new GridViewColumn()
            {
                Header = col.ColumnName,
                // One of these works, displaymember has higher priority
                DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(col.ColumnName),
                CellTemplate = template
            };

            grid.Columns.Add(gridColumn);
        }
        lvMain.ItemsSource = ((IListSource)table).GetList();
    }
```

And XAML code:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="cellTemplate" x:Name="cellTemplate">
        <DataTemplate.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        </DataTemplate.Resources>
        <Border >
            <StackPanel>
                <!-- How can I bind here? -->
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<ListView x:Name="lvMain">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: You need to create a `DataTemplate` per property to bind to. Yoy may create the them programmatically using the `XamlReader.Parse` method.

Comment: @mm8 Do you mean creating each cell in code behind?

Comment: Yes. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a `DataTemplate` per property to bind to.

You may create the them programmatically using the `XamlReader.Parse` method:

```
private static DataTemplate CreateTemplate(string sourceProperty)
{
    string Xaml = "<DataTemplate xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\">" +
        "        <DataTemplate.Resources>" +
        "        <Style TargetType=\"Border\">" +
        "            <Style.Triggers>" +
        "                <Trigger Property=\"IsMouseOver\" Value=\"True\">" +
        "                    <Setter Property=\"Background\" Value=\"Black\"/>" +
        "                </Trigger>" +
        "                <Trigger Property=\"IsMouseOver\" Value=\"False\">" +
        "                    <Setter Property=\"Background\" Value=\"White\"/>" +
        "                </Trigger>" +
        "            </Style.Triggers>" +
        "        </Style>" +
        "        </DataTemplate.Resources>" +
        "        <Border>" +
        "            <StackPanel>" +
        "                <TextBlock Text=\"{Binding " + sourceProperty + "}\"/>" +
        "            </StackPanel>" +
        "        </Border>" +
        "    </DataTemplate>";

    return XamlReader.Parse(Xaml) as DataTemplate;
}
```

---

```
var gridColumn = new GridViewColumn()
{
    Header = col.ColumnName,
    CellTemplate = CreateTemplate(col.ColumnName)
};
```

Comment: Amazing! That's exactly what I was looking for